# React Router and Authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react and learning how to react-router to achieve routing. As a part of my sample app I was trying to put an authenticator on every path that's a part of the site. I'm following this example: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js

And here is my sample code:

```
  render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout}/>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("app"));
```

And here is what requireAuth does:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if(!auth.isUserLoggedIn()) {
    replace({
      path: "/login",
      state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
    });
  }
}
```

The difference between what I'm doing and what the example does is that the example puts the auth functionality only on one route (dashboard), where as I want to put it on every route. But the example stops working and starts throwing error

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

and I think rightly so because /login is a subroute of / and because requireAuth is redirecting to the sub route, it just try to authenticate again and keeps trying for ever. I'm probably missing a simple fix here to get this to work, but am not able to figure what is the best way to do it.

What can I do to enable authentication at every level of the site?

Answer (score 2):

Answer of @DemoUser is almost correct and @KumarM how you can login if you need to be authenticated to see login page ? here is what you can do

```
render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout}/>
      <Route path="/dashboard" onEnter={requireAuth} >
       <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
       <Route path="about" component={About}/>
       <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
     </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("app"));
```

whats happening here ?

1. login and logout page need not to be authenticated
2. all child components of Dashboard will automatically be authenticated

Comment: I would love to accept this as an answer, but as I mentioned above, I do not want to create another path in the middle just to get to what I need to do.

Comment: there is no way you can put authentication on root, if you  still want to do it , then you can try with if condition depending on current path and return the component, but that's not a good approach

Answer (score 1):

I think you must've figured it out by now but I stumbled across this today, so I thought of sharing this:

If you are adamant on securing every resource of your application, I'd suggest thinking twice. What @abhirathore2006 said is: users of your application shouldn't be authenticated to access the login component. Should they?

You are correct in assuming that the 'Maximum call stack size increased' is because of infinite redirects happening and you can try to avoid it by doing a null check or something.

The point is, you'd just need to place the onEnter hook on the /logout, /inbox & /about components and leave the /login as is. Otherwise you could try wrapping these components in a HOC or use the newer react-router4 approach to get what you need.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could change your route so that, the pages that do not require login, can be rendered without need of authentication, as:

```
render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout}/>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("app"));
```

If user is already loggedin `requireAuth` does not do anything, and your Inbox component is rendered.

Comment: Thanks, I see that in the example as well. But as I mentioned in my question, I'd like to make every route authenticated before it can be accessed. So need to enable it on every route (trying to avoid explicitly putting the onEnter method on every route other than login).